# Check if association exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a User model like this :

```
has_one :car
```

and Car model :

```
belongs_to :user
```

How can I check which users don't have cars?

Comment: Where do you want to check it? In a test, in a validation? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @SimoneCarletti they should be covered with validations but still there are cases, I'm trying to find out the damage

Comment: If you want to check if a user has a car then `@user.car.blank?` will return true if the user doesn't own a car. Or if you wan to get all the users who don't own a car then `User.where(id: Car.pluck(:user_id).uniq)`

Comment: @ManojMonga, User.where(id: Car.pluck(:user_id).uniq) - definitely find users who has cars, not who don't own. You are mistaken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a query like this:

```
User.includes(:car).where(cars: {user_id: nil})
```

I would suggest extracting it into a scope:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def self.without_car
    includes(:car).where(cars: {user_id: nil})
  end
end
```

Then you can simply write

```
User.without_car
```

**Edit**

For clarification: behind the scenes, this query will be issued:

```
SELECT "users"."name" FROM "users"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "cars" ON "cars"."user_id" = "users"."id"
WHERE "cars"."user_id" IS NULL
```

The join will result in an empty row for the `car.user_id`, so we can simply check if that row is `NULL` (or, from Active Record's point of view, `nil`).

By the way, this also works for `has_many` relationships, just change the argument to `includes` to plural as well. Note that the argument to `where` always needs to be plural, since it's the table name.

Comment: is that really called a scope?

Comment: @devanand I guess it's a historically grown name, see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: May the downvoter be so kind and explain what's wrong with this? I want to improve my answer.

Comment: Will the user_id ever be nil? I think its the first condition for the foreign_key constraint that the column must not let be blank. If there is any car with nil user_id that means this car doesn't belongs to any user.

Comment: @p11y: thanks. i've read the documentation. at least it's a class method which is exactly the same as a scope :) thanks.

Comment: @ManojMonga: the model doesn't imply a foreign key constraint. so it is possible to have a nil for the user_id

Comment: But here the point is how the having nil `user_id` in cars get us the user without cars?

Comment: @ManojMonga please verify that you are correct before downvoting and claiming that my answer is wrong. I have checked and it works. See my edit, it includes the query. The join will result in an empty row for the `car.user_id` so we can simply check if that is `NULL`.

Comment: By the way I wasn't the downvoter. I was just curious about the query. I just verified it as well. +1 for the clarification buddy......... :)

Comment: Nice answer, but that's a method not a scope. Here's the actual scope: `scope :without_car, includes(:car).where(cars: {user_id: nil})` Either works, although the scope is marginally better maybe because I can apply the scope onto a set of User instances or on the class itself, while your method is a class method.

Comment: @Niall someone else already mentioned that and I pointed them to this link. I just happen to prefer class methods ;-) http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes